# Cannot change column type from date to timestamp with time zone in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I would like to change type of column in PostgreSQL from date to timestamp with time zone. But execution of follow sql continues until I stop it despite there are only 3 records in the table and without any error or successful result.

```
alter table some_table
    alter column column_date type timestamp
        using to_timestamp(extract(epoch from column_date))
```

At the same time `select to_timestamp(extract(epoch from column_date)) from some_table` is executing correct without any error.

I've try another variations for *using* expression

- `using column_date::timestamptz`
- `using timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + (column_date + interval '0 second') * interval '1 second'`
- `using column_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`
  with no effect.

If there are null value of the column in all records type changing immediately with simple alter sql

```
alter table some_table
    alter column column_date type timestamp
        using column_date::timestamp with time zone
```

*I use PostgreSQL 12*

Is there appropriate method to change date to timestamp with time zone?

P.S. I know I can do this task by creating a new column with appropriate type and then swap them:))

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example how you would use UTC as time zone

```
CREATE tABLE tm( mydate date)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO TM VALUES('2022-01-01'),('2021-01-01'),('2020-01-01')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 3
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM tm
```

| mydate |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 |
| 2021-01-01 |
| 2020-01-01 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

```
ALTER TABLE tm
ALTER COLUMN myDate TYPE timestamp with time zone
USING myDate::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM tm
```

| mydate |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00+00 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00+00 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i8Dta11t)